# GET Requests fails with 401 Unauthorized Error when the url has query parameters

Tags: oauth, jira-rest-api, http-status-code-401

I am making a Rest API call to Jira in C# using Oauth 1.0a. So far I have been able to get the access token and make API calls using this token to fetch the projects, issue, create tickets, and add attachments without any issue.

I am facing an issue when I have some query parameters in the URL wherein I am getting a response **oauth_problem="signature_invalid"**

> "{WWW-Authenticate: OAuth
> realm="https%3A%2F%2Fxxxx-stage.dummy.com%2Fjira", OAuth
> realm="https%3A%2F%2Fxxxx-stage.dummy.com%2Fjira",
> oauth_problem="signature_invalid",
> oauth_signature="fxrHjNmz3C0gPClh667xKO93fU9PI%2FFAy2o%2B0tA98oso3d%2FiHF957LnMJdKWdmN1w6lJIgEYA5WLpvRuv65IIgAVeSWQWyyE2iqKY5NKpVe8w9lNKJpp6jVX3OzUfhZFsUmNcfwmrfEzDfq0DFKHbDltA9KX51daMWfE5bOxUwA%3D",
> oauth_signature_base_string="GET%26https%253A%252F%252Fxxxx-stage.dummy.com%252Fjira%252Frest%252Fapi%252F2%252Fissue%252Fcreatemeta%26oauth_callback%253Doob%2526oauth_consumer_key%253DOauthKey-elite%2526oauth_nonce%253D161227630350881010%2526oauth_signature_method%253DRSA-SHA1%2526oauth_timestamp%253D1612276303%2526oauth_token%253DIuXbcYTqh5kAIbirTWg7zqzJhVITFHny%2526oauth_version%253D1.0",
> oauth_signature_method="RSA-SHA1"
>
> Date: Tue, 02 Feb 2021 14:34:19 GMT   Strict-Transport-Security:
> max-age=16000000; includeSubDomains; preload   X-XSS-Protection:
> 1;mode=block   Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
> X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none   X-Download-Options: noopen
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
> Content-Length: 654   }

The actual url is "https://xxxx-stage.dummy.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?projectKeys=Elite&issueTypeNames=Task&expand=projects.issuetypes.fields"

After sorting and encoding the url and the parameters I have the below string which I am signing using RSA-SHA1.

> GET&https%3A%2F%2Fxxxx-stage.dummy.com%2Fjira%2Frest%2Fapi%2F2%2Fissue%2Fcreatemeta&expand%3Dprojects.issuetypes.fields%26issueTypeNames%3DTask%26projectKeys%3DSciFiProject%26oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3DOauthKey-elite%26oauth_nonce%3D161227476865431774%26oauth_signature_method%3DRSA-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1612274768%26oauth_token%xxxxcYTqh5kAIbirTWg7zqzJhVITFHny%26oauth_version%3D1.0

And the query parameters are not added to the Authorization header. It only has the OAuth parameters.

Also, I noticed that in the encoded URL, the "GET" method name and the URL are separated by "&". And the first parameter "expand" and the end of the URL "createmeta" are separated by "&" but the other parameters which follow including the OAuth parameters are URL encoded. The strange thing is this works for other URLs with no query parameters.

This has been already answered here [GET fails with 401 (Unauthorized) when query parameter is involved due to invalid OAuth signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677370/get-fails-with-401-unauthorized-when-query-parameter-is-involved-due-to-invali/66011541#66011541), I have tried doing the steps mentioned there but I guess I might be missing something.

Can somebody guide me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the problem myself. The issue was with the way the SignatureBaseString was formed. The parameters have to be sorted and then encoded. So in my case the issue was with the highlighted parameter .

> GET&https%3A%2F%2Fxxxx-stage.dummy.com%2Fjira%2Frest%2Fapi%2F2%2Fissue%2Fcreatemeta&expand%3Dprojects.issuetypes.fields%26issueTypeNames%3DTask%26**projectKeys%3DSciFiProject**%26oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3DOauthKey-elite%26oauth_nonce%3D161227476865431774%26oauth_signature_method%3DRSA-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1612274768%26oauth_token%xxxxcYTqh5kAIbirTWg7zqzJhVITFHny%26oauth_version%3D1.0

The highlighted parameter is supposed to be at the end of the encoded string. So basically the solution is to sort the parameters in the ascending order, Separate each parameter with "&" and then URL encode the parameter string. If two parameters have the same name, then order them based on their value.

> GET&https%3A%2F%2Fxxxx-stage.dummy.com%2Fjira%2Frest%2Fapi%2F2%2Fissue%2Fcreatemeta&expand%3Dprojects.issuetypes.fields%26issueTypeNames%3DTask%26oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3DOauthKey-elite%26oauth_nonce%3D161228695355767297%26oauth_signature_method%3DRSA-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1612286953%26oauth_token%3xcxccYTqh5kAIbirTWg7zqzJhVITFHny%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26**projectKeys%3DElite**

more info can be found here regarding encoding of parameters.
https://oauth.net/core/1.0/#encoding_parameters