# Evernote OAuth authentication using Postman fails at the first step

Tags: delphi, oauth, postman, evernote

I am trying to connect to the Evernote API using Postman.

The first step in the documentation titled "Generate a temporary token" indicates to use a GET against the endpoint https://www.evernote.com/oauth with the request parameters oauth_callback, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, and oauth_version and gives an example thus

```
https://www.evernote.com/oauth?oauth_callback=http://www.example.com&oauth_consumer_key=sample-api-key-4121&oauth_nonce=3166905818410889691&oauth_signature=T0+xCYjTiyz7GZiElg1uQaHGQ6I=&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1429565574&oauth_version=1.0
```

When I use Postman, I end up with the following similar URL

```
https://www.evernote.com/oauth?oauth_consumer_key=internalreadonlyapp-4219&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1709895348&oauth_nonce=6xGqqqBpGyb&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&oauth_signature=WhBAJreL1KwCQ%2BYrZQh57JT3nO4%3D
```

but I always get a 401 Unauthorised error.

This leads me to believe that the documentation https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php/ is maybe missing some critical info.

I can't use one of the supplied SDK's as I'm integrating a Delphi app with Evernote and there isn't a Delphi SDK, so I need to write my own integration (which I've done many times in the past for other applications), but I can't understand why I'm failing at the very first step here.

Has anyone got Postman working with Evernote or knows what I'm missing ?

Comment: How are you generating the value for `oauth_signature` that you have in the URL? Their documentation does not seem to have any info about what data it is expecting to be included when generating the signature

Comment: @DaveNottage I'm not generating it, Postman is. As far as I can see it uses the oauth_ fields in alphabetical order.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49696303/80901

Comment: I would try one of the existing SDKs and compare the generated URL.